# evaluar valor de div asignado en php

Tags: php, ajax

Mi problema es el siguiente. Al intentar evaluar el valor de un **div** asignado mediante **PHP** con **ajax**, no puedo lograr evaluar la cadena VACIA "" como verdadero. Aca un ejemplo sencillo de mi problema. mensajeAjax pertenece a una etiqueta **div**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function comprobar(nick){  
  var url = '/reg/ControlCampos.php';  
  var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater( 'mensajeAjax', url, { method: 'get', onComplete: function(){
    if (

***document.getElementById("mensajeAjax").innerHTML==""*** //NOT WORKING

)
       //ACTION
  }});
} </scrip>`
```

Código **PHP** de **ControlCampos.php**

```
<?php echo ""; ?>`
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta, estás en SO en español; de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Intentaste poniendo `document.getElementById('mensajeAjax').value=""; ` ?

Comment: VirusDetected, editare mi pregunta para detallar que "mensajeAjax" pertenece a un div, el cual no tiene value segun lo que lei. Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. La respuesta del archivo php tiene espacios en blancos, por lo cual no es posible evaluar directamente la sentencia

`document.getElementById("mensajeAjax").innerHTML==""`,

la solucion fue

`document.getElementById("mensajeAjax").innerHTML.trim()==""`

que quita los espacios en blancos.